# Use breakpoints on Vuetify text

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify 1.5.24

I want to change the text-size based on certain breakpoints. I thought it was possible in the following way:

```
<h1 class="text-xs-display-1 text-md-display-2">Hello World</h1>
```

This however doesn't work, maybe it's not possible in Vuetify 1.5.24? I'm currently not able to upgrade to Vuetify 2.x

Comment: `text-xs-display-1`
It is not documented in v1.5.x while the syntax is documented in v2.5.x

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added in [version 2.3](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.3.0)

As stated there

> Scale your headings and other text with the new responsive typography classes.

You will have to make it work manually. CSS breakpoints would be my approach.